# How to retrieve help for Pandas methods using '??'

Tags: pandas

I am new to Pandas, trying to learn the basics from lecture videos. In one of these the presenter demonstrates that one can call help on methods using ??. 
For example if I have loaded a dataframe df then typing df.**getitem**?? should print the docstring as well as the source code to the console. This would be really great to have but it doesn't work for me! I tried different variants of the command and also tried to find a comment online on this, without success.

What do I need to type in order to retrieve the docstring as well as the source code of a Pandas method? Thanks a lot for your help !

(I am using Python 3.5 and PyCharm in case that makes a difference)

Comment: This sounds like something that [ipython](https://ipython.org/)  does which is why you don't see anything, you should use ipython as it has lots of useful interactive tools

Comment: @EdChum thanks a lot for the comment! I now noticed that the lecturer was actually mentioning 'IPython' before talking about the '??' functionality. If you like to post your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your lecturer was using [ipython](https://ipython.org/) as this does support [dynamic object information](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#dynamic-object-information). For instance this is the output in ipython when you do `df.__getitem__??` you see the following:

[image]

I strongly recommend ipython for interactive python development, you'll find a lot of devs using this for data exploration and analysis, the workbook is really useful for saving your commands and the output